# Assigning entity instance instead of entity id creates new record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these two tables:

```cs
public class FiscalYear
{   
    ... other fields  
    public int FiscalYears_Id { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class SkipHeader
{
    ... other fields
    public int FiscalYears_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual FiscalYear FiscalYear { get; set; }
}
```

Attempting to create a new `SkipHeader` like so:

```cs
var skipHeader = new SkipHeader()
{
    ... other fields get assigned to
    FiscalYear = Session.FiscalYear,
}
```

Will cause the database to create a new `FiscalYear` record instead of using the `Session.FiscalYear` which is simply a static property that gets assigned to at program start. However, if I assign the `FiscalYears_Id` instead:

```cs
var skipHeader = new SkipHeader()
{
    ... other fields get assigned to
    FiscalYears_Id = Session.FiscalYear.FiscalYears_Id,
}
```

The program uses the existing record as expected.

This bug eluded me and my colleague for months! Now that I found a solution, I would like to know WHY this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This bug eluded me and my colleague for months! Now that I found a
> solution, I would like to know WHY this is the case?

This occurs because the DbContext doesn't know about your FiscalYear object instance, such as whether it represents a new record or an existing one.

Take the following example:

```
var fiscalYear = new FiscalYear { Id = 4, Name = "2019/20" };
var skipHeader = new SkipHeader { FiscalYear = fiscalYear };
context.SkipHeaders.Add(skipHeader);
context.SaveChanges();
```

`fiscalYear` in this instance is an object instance that has been given an ID and Name. When we associate it to a new SkipHeader and add the SkipHeader to the DbContext, EF will see this fiscalYear. Since it isn't an object tracked by the context, it treats it as a new entity like the SkipHeader.

Depending on how your entities are configured for dealing with the PK will determine what happens.

If your PK (Id) is set up as an Identity column (DB will populate) then the FiscalYear will be inserted and assigned the next available Id value. After the `SaveChanges()` call, fiscalYear.Id would be "6" or "22" or whatever the next new ID assigned to it would be. (Not "4")
If your PK is not an Identity column (App will populate) and a FiscalYear row already exists in the DB for ID 4, then EF will throw a duplicate key Exception on `SaveChanges()`.

Where people get confused is that they assume that since the FiscalYear was at one point (Say during a web request) loaded from a DbContext, it is still somehow acting as a tracked entity when passed into another method outside of the scope of that DbContext. (During another update web request) It's not.  When a web request for instance accepts a FinancialYear as a parameter from the client, it is deserializing a FinancialYear. As far as EF is concerned, that is absolutely no different than the `new FinancialYear { }` example above. The DbContext is not aware of that entity.

Take the following example:

```
FiscalYear fiscalYear = null;
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    fiscalYear = context.FiscalYears.Single(x => x.Id == 4);
}

using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var skipHeader = new SkipHeader { FiscalYear = fiscalYear };
    context.SkipHeaders.Add(skipHeader);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This provides a basic outline of a Fiscal Year that was loaded by one instance of a DbContext, but then referenced by another instance of a DbContext. When `SaveChanges` is called, you will get a behaviour like you are getting now. This is what essentially happens in web requests, as when an entity is returned, the entity definition is merely a contract and the Entity is serialized to send to the client. When it comes back into another request, a new untracked object is deserialized.

As a general rule, Entities should not be passed outside the scope of the DbContext they were read from. EF does support this via detaching and re-attaching entities, but this is honestly more trouble than it is typically worth because you cannot 100% rely on just attaching an entity using `DbContext.Attach()` as often there can be conditional cases where another entity instance is already being tracked by a context and the `Attach` will fail. In these cases you'd need to replace references with the already tracked entity. (Messy conditional logic to catch possible scenarios) References are everything when dealing with EF. Two different object references with the same key & values are treated as separate and different objects by EF. Rather than passing references around, it's usually a lot simpler, and better to pass just the FK. This has the benefit of being a smaller payload for web requests.

One option you've found out is to update via the FK:

```
var skipHeader = new SkipHeader()
{
    ... other fields get assigned to
    FiscalYears_Id = Session.FiscalYear.FiscalYears_Id,
}
```

This works, however when you have entities that are exposing both FK (FiscalYears_Id) and navigation property (FiscalYear) you can potentially find mismatch scenarios when updating records. This is something to be careful with as an application evolves.

For instance, take an example where you are editing an existing SkipHeader with a FiscalYears_Id of "4". This will have an associated FiscalYear reference available with a PK of "4".

Take the following code:

```
var skipHeader = context.SkipHeaders.Include(x => x.FiscalYear).Single(x => x.Id == skipHeaderId);
skipHeader.FiscalYears_Id = newFiscalYearId; // update FK from "4" to "6"

var fiscalYearId = skipHeader.FiscalYear.Id; // still returns "6"
context.SaveChanges();
```

We set the FK value on the skip header, however that does not update the reference for FiscalYear until *after* we call `SaveChanges`. This can be an important detail when dealing with FKs alongside navigation properties. Now normally we wouldn't bother going to the Navigation Property to get the ID again, but any code we call that is expecting the new FiscalYear reference to be updated will have a different behavior depending on whether SaveChanges had been called before or after the code in question. If before, all FiscalYear details will be for the *old* fiscal year even though we changed the FK reference.

This can also lead to odd Lazy Loading errors as well such as:

```
var skipHeader = context.SkipHeaders.Single(x => x.Id == skipHeaderId);
skipHeader.FiscalYears_Id = newFiscalYearId; // update FK from "4" to "6"

var fiscalYearId = skipHeader.FiscalYear.Id; // NullReferenceException!
context.SaveChanges();
```

Normally, provided you have lazy loading enabled loading a SkipHeader without eager loading the FiscalYear (`.Include(x => x.FiscalYear)`)and then querying a property from the FiscalYear would lazy load this relative. However, if you change the SkipHeader's FiscalYear_ID FK and then try to access a property off the FiscalYear before calling `SaveChanges()`, you will get a `NullReferenceException` on the FiscalYear. EF will NOT lazy load either the old or new FiscalYear entity.  Bugs in behaviour like that commonly creep in as applications get developed and code starts calling common functions that assume they are dealing with complete entities.

The alternative to setting updated values for known rows by FK is to load the entity to associate, and associate it by reference:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var fiscalYear = context.FiscalYears.Single(x => x.Id == fiscalYearId);
    var skipHeader = new SkipHeader()
    {
        ... other fields get assigned to
        FiscalYear = fiscalYear;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This example just uses a locally scoped DbContext. If your method has an injected context then use that instead. The context will return any cached, known instance of the Fiscal Year or retrieve it from the DB. If the FiscalYear ID is invalid then that operation will throw an exception specific to the Fiscal Year not being found due to the `Single()` call rather than a more vague FK violation on `SaveChanges()`. (Not an issue when there is only one FK relationship, but in entities that have dozens of relationships...)

The advantage of this approach is that the FiscalYear will be in the scope of the DbContext so any methods/code using it will have a valid reference. The entities can define the navigation properties without exposing the extra FK values,using `.Map(x => x.MapKey())` [EF6] or Shadow Properties [EFCore] instead to avoid 2 sources of truth for FK values.

This hopefully will provide some insight into what EF is doing and why it resulted in the behaviour you've seen and/or any errors or buggy behaviour you might have also come across.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have pretty standard setup with `DbContext` being scoped (per request) dependency - the reason is that the new instance of your `DbContext` does not track the `Session.FiscalYear` instance - so it creates new. Another way to solve this is using [`DbContext.Attach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-3.1):

```
context.Attach(Session.FiscalYear);
var skipHeader = new SkipHeader()
{
    ... other fields get assigned to
    FiscalYears_Id = Session.FiscalYear.FiscalYears_Id,
}
// save skipHeader
```

[More](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/change-tracker) about change tracker in EF.